# View's content disappear after dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
func presentPicker(sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = LASignPickerViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let navBar = LANavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    presentViewController(navBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func dismiss(sender: UIButton) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Presenting works fine, dismissing too.
But after dismissing on the main view all views are disappearing after 1 second.

There remains only the background color.

[Main View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRP4i.png)

**UPDATE**:

In the debug view hierarchy all right!
And working - slides and button touches.

????

Comment: Does it work same if you use  dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) ?

Comment: @SMi, no, but disappear more faster.

Comment: Do you want this? as your problem was disappearing after 1 second.

Comment: @SMi, My problem is that after returning to the first viewcontroller of the views (collection view, navigation controller, page controller) disappeared

Comment: @AndreyOshev are you using xib or storyboard?

Comment: @MuruganandhamK code, w/o SB or XIB

Answer (score 1):

If you call directly `dismissViewControllerAnimated` without any object,it will dismiss all views on the main view

For dismissing any view, you need to write that view and then call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method

like for dismissing an alert 
    `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What you have done LANavigationController(rootViewController: vc) here?

Comment: add navigation controller to the view

Answer (score 0):

To present a View controller:

```
let LASignPickerViewControllerObj= self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LASignPickerViewControllerIdentifier") as? LASignPickerViewController

self.navigationController?.presentViewController(LASignPickerViewControllerObj!, animated: true)
```

To pop a View Controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```